# prevent mu4e convert html email to text when replying email

Tags: mu4e

If some people send emails to me, they use outlook or other modern email client, writing html email with image. When I reply these html emails, mu4e usually converted them into text content, it make other people uncomfortable. They complain to me why use this email client(mu4e).
I want to know if it has a way to keep email original format without changing it when replying emails using mu4e(maybe org mode can help, but I do not know).

Comment: What is your mu4e config?  Have you changed the value of `mu4e-html2text-command`?

Comment: How an email is quoted for replying should be independant of how it is rendered for our own viewing (unless explicitly asked for), so I'd love to see a full answer for this question.

Comment: @Qudit Yes, I changed the mu4e-html2text-command to view html content in email.